# Hall effect sensor operational distance from magnet

Tags: magnetics, physics, hall-effect

I want to use a this [hall effect sensor](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MH04-11S-300W/374-1398-ND/5270605) to detect the presence of magnet.  I'm pretty sure I understand how to use the hall effect sensor, but I'm not sure how to calculate the distance the sensor can detect a magnet of a given Gauss.  I'm not even sure that the Gauss rating is relevant to the question.

The `Output On` rating is listed as 35G and the `Output Off` is listed as 25G.  If I use a magnet like [this one](http://www.magnet4sale.com/neodymium-magnets-n42-1-4-cube-ndfeb-rare-earth-magnets/) (13,200 Gauss), can it be detected up to 6 inches (15 cm) away?

I found an [online calculator](http://www.intemag.com/calculators/Flux_Density_Plain_Rect.html) to use but it appears to calculate the rating between two magnets and not a magnet and a sensor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends a bit on how the magnet is oriented with respect to the sensor.

I would approach this question by first making the approximation that your magnet is a point dipole. Even though it is a cube, this approximation will be reasonable when you are an inch or so from the cube.

Therefore, you can use [this equation for flux density at a given point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole). You will need to figure out the magnetic moment based on the specifications from the magnet manufacturer.

Then, determine the critical distance which results in a field of 35 Gauss.